# DRY in WinRT application

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, caliburn.micro

I develop WinRT application with hamburger menu. How can I extract it as distinct user control to reduce code duplication? This menu is same on all the pages.

Or can I create main page with menu and embed other page inside it? Like html iframe. Caliburn Micro can do this, but I don't know whether it is good idea.

Help me to organize this component.

Comment: well, encapsulate all the code inside an usercontrol an that's all, you can then add it to as many pages as you need

Comment: Here's an example on how to use usercontrols in WINRT: http://www.dotnetcurry.com/windowsapp/930/create-user-control-xaml-csharp

Comment: Did you tried this? https://github.com/ilio/HamburgerMenu/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's best practice to put the splitview control into one page (e.g. Mainpage) and to to navigate only the content of the SplitView.Content.

```
  <SplitView>
        <SplitView.Pane>
            <Button Content="Click"></Button>
        </SplitView.Pane>
        <SplitView.Content>
            <Frame Name="MainFrame"></Frame>
        </SplitView.Content>
    </SplitView>
```

To navigate simply exchange the content of the frame:

```
MainFrame.Navigate(typeof(SomePage));
```

Answer (score 1):

4 ways to achieve this
1) create the control since you indicated Windows Phone 8.1 since SplitView doesn't exists in there.
2) Buy Teleriks controls for WinRT (UI for Windows Universal, only targets Windows 8.1 style Universals atm) (still need work IMO)
3) Use that free one above in the comment...
4) Move to Windows 10, its in the framework

as for usage with Caliburn.Micro bind to the Load event of the Frame that is placed into the Content pane.  From there navigate as normal.  CM 3.0 Beta1 has an example of this with Windows 10 UAPs